# Vertically align elements using CSS

Tags: css

I just want to vertically align elements in my header. That would be really easy with tables but can't figure how to do it with CSS. I want to vertically align all 3 elements withing the black bar : "Logo", "Rechercher" and the text input.

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:100%;
}

#header {
background-color:#303030;
height:3em;
}

#logo {
color:#EEEEEE;
font-size:2em;
line-height:1.5em;
padding:0 30px 0px 10px;
display:inline;
}

#recherche {
color:#EEEEEE;
font-size:1.5em;
display:inline;
}

#recherche input {
width:300px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius:4px;
}
```

And the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainframe.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <form id="recherche" action="/" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="rechercher">Rechercher</label>
    <input type="text" name="recherche">
</form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a form, not a label.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution that works fine:
you can add `line-height:size_px` to each element that you want it's children to be aligned vertically. (e.g. size_px := 10px). The `line-height` should be the same as the parent height (`height`).

try:

jsfiddle.net/rjCBR/

Comment: This is a poor solution if there's a possibility that the elements might wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `body` and `#header` of your css with the following code:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:100%;
width: 100%;
display: table;
}

#header {
background-color:#303030;
height:3em;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Vertical-align: middle;`, as other have suggested, aligns the bottom of the text for each element, which looks odd for an input box where the bottom of the actual element will be substantially below the text.

Try adding the following properties to the input css

```css
height: 24px;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/jgBCR/)

Comment: Remember to upvote good answers and mark as accepted the best answer, not just here but in future discussions as well to promote the best possible content.